# Transfer data between two Mac via USB-C

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, file-transfer

I want to transfer files between two late 2016 MacBook Pros. I have a USB-C data cable from my external USB-C hard drive.

Can I connect the Macs using that USB-C data cable to transfer files?
Or do I need to put one of the Macs in target disk mode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You needs to put one of the computer in Target Disk Mode (Press T on startup) and connect another USB-C equipped Mac with a USB-C cable (or [USB-C to USB Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter)/[Cable](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HHSM2ZM/B/belkin-usb-a-to-usb-c-cable-usb-31) for older computer) Note that the USB-C cable that come with your MacBook Pro 2016 does not work.

There are a more complicated method (and this requires a [Thunderbolt 3 Cable](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKK12ZM/A/belkin-thunderbolt-3-cable-05-m) (or use a [Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) and a [Thunderbolt 2 Cable](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD862LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-05-m) for older computers) and both computer have to be a Mac that support Thunderbolt. But this does not requires Target Disk Mode. Connect both Macs with the Thunderbolt cable (or with the adapter) and go to System Preferences > Network on both Mac. Go to Thunderbolt bridge (add one if it doesn't exist) and there set configure IPv4 to manually on both. Now set Subnet Mask on both to 255.255.255.0, now give two IPs to both computer (i.e. 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.2). Now you can use File Sharing (and other shadings) with the two Macs by Thunderbolt when you use the IP address.

Comment: Does target disk mode work if I have FileVault enabled?

Comment: @Lukas I don't have a FileVault enabled Mac with me at the moment, you can trying though. If that doesn't work than you need to use the second method.

Comment: @Lukas Yes, Target Mode does work when FileVault 2 enabled. But you may need another USB-C to USB-C cable, the one from Apple with MacBook Pro with Touch Bar doesn't work with Target Mode.

Comment: Slight variation on what Tom Shen said: If you have an [Apple Thunderbolt 3 cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ4H2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb‑c-cable-08-m), you may not even need to configure IPV4 manually. Apple's USB-C power cables won't work for this, but if you connect two Macs with a Thunderbolt 3 cable (the one with a lightning-bolt icon on the connectors), then you can leave Thunderbolt bridge's IPV4 setting set to DHCP, and it will give you a self-assigned IP address. Then you can use Sharing as described by Tom Shen.

Comment: Some explanation on why Apple's USB-C power cables won't work would be great.

Comment: Because Apple wanted to save money by only providing the power channel of the usb-c cable and not the data channel

Comment: "use a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter and a Thunderbolt 2 Cable for older computers"
It's very expensive. Anybody knows cheaper analogs?

Comment: @DenisRozhnev " It's very expensive. Anybody knows cheaper analogs? "  No, there is no cheaper analog.  Thunderbolt is a high speed interface and so requires fine tuned cables to work.  If you want overnight delivery you have to pay the freight.  Depending on the Apple computers involved you may be able to use FireWire, but FireWire is not as fast and given the rarity of cables and adapters today it may not be any lower cost than Thunderbolt.

Comment: Ohh man this line was all i need `USB-C cable that come with your MacBook Pro 2016 does not work` 